# Is the Design tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist-request

So there's a [design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag and I'm struggling to imagine a situation where it'd actually be useful; there's much more specific and relevant tags like flat-design and responsive-design that have value, and already-kinda-nebulous tags like interaction-design and website-design,  I can't think of a reason any question on this site could have *only* this tag and be meaningfully categorized, and that's usually a sign of a poor tag.

Kill?

Comment: My vote is to kill it.

Answer (score 4):

The term 'design' is simply too broad of a term for it to be a tag.

Specific tags may make sense such as:

- graphic-design
- design-thinking
- ui-design

But 'design' by itself just has no context so could really apply to most anything on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Kill.

The "design" tag seems to be more noise than signal. It doesn't get used very often (299 tags ever). And when it does get used, there's often a "[specifier]-design" tag used, too. After reviewing [the list questions tagged "design"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design?sort=newest&pagesize=50), I can't see a meaningful pattern emerging. Contrast that with [the questions tagged "user research"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-research), which is clearly a topical grouping.

According to [SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), "A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions." I don't see this with the "design" tag.

I think the "design" tag is not needed and should be deleted.

Comment: A "design" tag is about as relevant as a "programming" tag on SO. There is always a more accurate tag, which you see on SO when you search for "programming" as a tag. Same thing applies in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that it is doubtful that any question would be general enough to *require* this tag, especially when things like [design-process](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-process) and [design-principles](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) exist.

Still, what harm is it doing?

And isn't it a bit unintuitive to not have a tag for the top level of a legitimate category of questions?  This is a bit different from killing a tag like user-experience, which would apply to *everything on the site*.

Forgive me if I'm ignorant of previous relevant discussions.

Comment: Re: "`what harm is it doing?`" it's making it possible to ask questions with no meaningful tag (or taking up one of only 5 tag slots), which makes the questions more difficult to find later, which makes it less likely that people will find existing questions before posting duplicates, which may cause a small bit of extra moderation work in closing these duplicates...which may be negligible.  Still, I think we should blacklist the tag.  On a site of people involved in information architecture, its a bit embarrassing to allow tags with essentially no meaning.

Comment: @3nafish, it is less than optimal specificity, but I don't agree it is meaningless.  Not all questions are about design.

Comment: What's an example of a question that isn't in some way related to design?

Comment: @3nafish, lots of questions under categories such as [tag:testing], [tag:user-research], and [tag:terminology] are not about design.

Comment: Yet they all relate directly to design.  Why test? To validate or inform designs. Why do user research? To provide a foundation for designs. Why use common terminology? To move toward standards of design.